# sorting an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array

```
array={'first','fifth','fourth','second','third'};
```

I want to sort this array how can this be done using javascript .Take notice that this is a small array I'm predicting only from first ti fifth but this array can be changed according to user input.

Comment: this will help you achieve what you want. [MDN Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: This is not an array. This is is incorrect structure in JavaScript. It can't be sorted, as it will throw a syntax error.

Comment: `['first','fifth','fourth','second','third']` should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sort() method sorts the items of an array.

```
var array = ['first','fifth','fourth','second','third'];
array.sort();
```

Comment: dude. if you are using examples from other sites, be kind enough to reference them.

Comment: and if that site is w3schools, just dont use it ;-)